# NGINX / RTMP / HLS live stream on Raspberry pi (Debian 8.4)

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, rtmp, hls

---

Debian 8.4 / Raspbian 8.0

Nginx 1.9.15

ffmpeg 2.6.8 (server side) / avconv 11.6-6:11.6-1~deb8u1+rpi1 (camera collect) . Avconv is a FFMPEG fork, it does work fine on raspbian.

---

Flow schema

cam-1 : raspberry pi / model B / raspbian 8.0 (Jessie) / avconv

mercure : debian server 8.4 (Jessie) / nginx / ffmpeg

**cam-1** [rapivid | avconv (ffmpeg)] -> **mercure** [nginx rtmp / hls]

---

I've read a lot of post on the web since 2 weeks about setting a live video streaming server that received video streams from a raspberry pi camera. don't worry about the raspberry streaming source , the problem is not focused on. 
The goal is to be able to read RTMP and HLS live streams on the remote NGINX server

**the facts :**

It works, I'am able to read the live stream from the RTMP/NGINX server via

```
ffplay rtmp://mercure/live/cam-1 (defaults to 1935 port)
```

***note*** :
 it doesn't using VLC and a QT5 app embedding QMediaPlayer / QMediaContent widgets.
 I've found out that VLC introduces issues with librtmp.so on debian and seems to be the same on window 7 (test also fails). source : debian blog. The QT5 issue is perhaps a side effect as QT5 perhaps uses vlc library ? I'm still investigating. The QT5 components can read any disk video file  but freeze on the first image when streaming with rtmp

Nginx hls module is installed.

**Camera (raspberry pi)**

To connect the video stream from the camera and publish it onto the NGINX rtmp server using raspivid and avconv (The FFMPEG fork) packages the command used is :

pull from the rasp cam (cam-1) :

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -hf -vf -fl -pf main -a 8 -mm matrix -w 640 -h 480 -g 250 -t 0 -b 2048000 -o -
```

push to the RTMP server (mercure)

```
avconv -re -i - -nostats -c copy -copyts -an -r 25 -f flv rtmp://mercure:1935/live/cam-1
```

the complete command embedded into a debian service is then

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -hf -vf -fl -pf main -a 8 -mm matrix -w 640 -h 480 -g 250 -t 0 -b 2048000 -o - | avconv -re -i - -nostats -c copy -copyts -an -r 25 -f flv rtmp://mercure:1935/live/cam-1
```

**RTMP / HTTP server side**

All posts seem to state on this type of configuration ( /etc/nginx.conf excerpt ). That works when reading pure rtmp strems via ffplay as mentioned above

```
rtmp {

        server {

            listen 1935;
            chunk_size 4000;

            application live {

                    live on;

            }

            application hls {
                    live on;              
                    hls on;
                    hls_path /tmp/hls;

            }
         }
}

http {

    server {

            server_name     mercure;

            location / {
                root   /var/www;
                index  index.html;
            }

            location /hls{

                    types {
                            video/MP2T ts;
                            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                    }

                    root /tmp;

                    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

            }

    }
}
```

I don't  really understand how nginx works with hls ... does the incoming stream from avconv (ffmpeg) is dynamically pushed to the /hls rtmp application ? when the camera stream is received, the /tmp/hls folder is created along with a cam-1-0.ts file .. but nothing else ... no m3u8 index ...

Trying to access hls resource with http://mercure/hls/cam-1 (.m3u8, .m3u ...) and the response is a 404 HTTP error : standard http behavior.

I've tryed to feed the /hls rtmp application by changing trought the live rtmp configuration section

```
application live {

  live on;
  exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://mercure/live/cam-1 -c copy -f flv rtmp://mercure/hls/cam-1;

}
```

I'am absolutely not confident in the nginx ability to manage HLS streams while documentation states on it.

**My question is : does anybody really succeed publishing incoming flv source to HLS stream using a FFMPEG transport and the NGINX / http - rtmp (/hls/dash) server?**

Answer (score 1):

Setup: raspivid -> ffmpeg -> rtmp -> hls[ts/m3u8] -> VideoJS

The NGINX RTMP HLS setup is very straight-forward, so I will not go through that.  I use hls_fragment size of 250ms and hls_playlist of 3s.  Feel free to use my NGINX RTMP HLS server. Just copy and pasted exactly what's in the rtmp section, but change 'stream_name' to something unique.  Similarly, change that in VideoJS so you can play it on your webpage.  I'm not guaranteeing the 2a application will exist forever, but I plan on it being my test application for a while.

1. Video Only, A
   raspivid -n -t 0 -h 480 -w 854 -fps 24 -b 1536000 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -c:v copy -f flv 'rtmp://streaming.sensored.solutions/2a/stream_name'
   Pros: Easiest, solid quality, no buffering.  Cons: ~10s latency
2. Video Only, B
   raspivid -n -t 0 -h 480 -w 854 -fps 15 -b 1080000 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -c:v copy -f flv 'rtmp://streaming.sensored.solutions/2a/stream_name'
   Pros: Low latency, under 5s.  Cons: Buffering, Quality
3. Video and Audio [USB via Sabrent and cheap 3.5mm mic]
   raspivid -n -t 0 -h 480 -w 854 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -i - -itsoffset 00:00:05.22 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:0,0 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:a aac -c:v copy -f flv 'rtmp://streaming.sensored.solutions/2a/stream_name'
   Pros: Quality, No Buffering, Synchronized audio/video.  Cons: High Bitrate [not good for multiple devices using same bandwidth], Latency ~12s - 15s

VideoJS:

```
    <!--Note, you should including the following in the HEAD of your HTML file: 
    <link href="http://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <div class="container" id="videojs_container">
        <section class="starter-template">
            <video id=video-js-player width=854 height=480 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay="true" data-setup="{}" preload="auto">
                <source src = "http://streaming.sensored.solutions/2a/stream_name/index.m3u8" type = "application/x-mpegURL">
            </video>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4/video.js"></script>
    <script src="http://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/node_modules/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs.hls.min.js"></script>
```